# Some actions doesn't work properly in non-English keyboard layout

Tags: autohotkey

Can anyone explain why some AHK actions doesn't work in non-English keyboard layout?

I'm working with both English and Ukrainian keyboard layouts.

This works perfectly in both:

```
F1:: MsgBox, Test
F1:: SendInput, !{Up} ; For convenience, should be tested in Windows Explorer
F1:: SendInput, a     ; Could be tested in Notepad, for example
```

But this will work only in English layout:

```
F1:: SendInput, ^a
F1:: SendInput, {Ctrl Down}a{Ctrl Up}
F1:: SendInput, ^{U+0061} ; Doesn't work even in English layout
```

If I switch keyboard to Ukrainian layout, instead of getting Ctrl-A, I will get just "a" (without Control).

As I discovered, the issue may be fixed with vk/sc codes:

```
F1:: SendInput, ^{vk41sc01E} ; Works in both English and Ukrainian layouts
```

But, I'm not a big fan of vk/sc codes, as I heared it sometimes works different depending on keyboard hardware.

Also, it's hard to understand the logic of this restriction. Well, I understand that sometimes we should define hotkeys with codes, that is

```
vk00sc000:: Do something
```

But why we are forced to use vk/sc codes **after the SendInput?**

---

So there are two qestions.

a) Why some commands works well in both layouts

- `Msgbox, Test`
- `SendInput, !{Up}`
- `SendInput, a`

but another commands works only in English layout (`SendInput, ^a`) ?

b) Is there some alternative of using sc/vk codes here?

---

I forgot to mention. I also tested `Send` and `SendPlay`, and they doesn't change anything. Also my scripts are saved in UTF8 with BOM, so I know we should not use just UTF8.

Comment: You haven't mentioned, if pressing Ctrl+a manually works in Ukraine layout. Also please specify the windows version. I have changed my keyboard quite a bit (Japanese->German) and use Send instead of SendInput. I still run into problems with some software. Problems are worse with windows 10

Comment: I use Win7. Of course, if I press Ctrl-a manually, it works correctly. For example, I could type some text in Notepad, press Ctrl-a and it will select all text.

Comment: Bit of a kludge, but if you find yourself restricted only to VK/SC codes, you could rely on a small bit of code to look up the VK/SC at runtime, which should account for the times it diverges from the expected VK/SC. See documentation here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKey.htm

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe Seems to be very useful for such issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: On AutoHotkey versions earlier than v1.1.27 (which should not require these workarounds), `GetKeyVK("a")` is almost certain to fail if the **default** keyboard layout does not include the "a" character. For the ASCII letters 'a' - 'z', what you want is the ordinal value of the upper-case version: `Ord("A")` or `Asc("A")`. Microsoft defines these VK codes as corresponding to the ASCII letters, so although their physical location may change depending on layout, they should always be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SendInput a` sends the *character* "a" by simulating the corresponding keystroke. However, on the Ukrainian layout, **there is no keystroke** corresponding to "a", so it sends the character using a fallback method, such as the method used to send `{U+0061}`. The details of this were recently added to the documentation under [Characters vs. keys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#characters).

Keyboard shortcuts (or hotkeys) are typically designed to react to a combination of modifier states and a **virtual key code**, such as 0x41 ('A'). Since the fallback methods do not use the expected virtual key code, they do not trigger the keyboard shortcut.

It typically is not meaningful to combine characters sent by a fallback method with modifier keys, so AutoHotkey v1.1.27 changed the behaviour of the 'a' - 'z' characters (when combined with a modifier) to fall back to the corresponding virtual key codes (which are equivalent to their upper-case ASCII counterparts) if they are not present on the keyboard layout.

So in other words, **it should just work with AutoHotkey v1.1.27+**.

As for question "a)":

- `Msgbox, Test` works well because it has nothing to do with the keyboard layout.
- `SendInput, !{Up}` works well because "Up" and other named keys (longer than one character) always correspond to the same VK or scan code. The scan code is used in this case to differentiate between Up and NumpadUp, which share the same VK code.
- `SendInput, a` works well because it is sent by a fallback method, which is also the reason that `SendInput, ^a` did **not** work well. If "a" was always equivalent to `{vk41}`, `SendInput, a` would produce the wrong character on the Ukrainian layout.

... and question "b)":

- In AutoHotkey versions earlier than v1.1.27, you must use the VK code (or SC code). However, you can avoid mystery numbers by passing the upper-case ASCII character to Ord (making the code a little more verbose): `Send % "^{" Format("vk{:x}", Ord("A")) "}"`. This can be abbreviated by creating a custom function to convert the letters to the corresponding virtual key codes.

Comment: Wow, Lexikos, it's you! Get an answer from you is like get an audience from the king :-) Thank you very much for creating and developing AutoHotkey!